# Redirect to login page if user is not login but don't redirect googlebot

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Im using "registered users only" plugin. Redirect the user to the Home screen if he / she is not logged in. But don't redirect Googlebot. I have all the IP numbers of Google. How do I let Google see my site? This is very important for SEO and how can I allow IP numbers I'VE been trying for 1 month? The plugin does not have such a feature.
Sorry for my bad english
This is google,yandex, alexa, bing, amazon bots ip:209.247.40.99,198.4.83.49,63.148.99.255,63.148.99.224,62.58.2.5,210.128.142.42,64.210.196.195,64.210.196.198,211.154.211.209,64.233.160.0,64.233.191.255,66.102.0.0,66.102.15.255,66.249.64.0,66.249.95.255,66.249.66.1,72.14.192.0,72.14.255.255,74.125.0.0,74.125.255.255